# Changing Choice Field value from a function

Tags: python, django

> models.py

```
class Leave_Application(models.Model):
    name = ..
    employee = ..
    leave_reason = ...
    status_field = (
        ('Pending','Pending'),
        ('Approved','Approved'),
        ('Declined','Declined'),
              )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=status_field,default='Pending')
```

I have both `approve` and `decline` function which are called by respective `approve` or `decline` button and then it sends confirmation message to the employee. I want now , with the 'respective function call' the value of status should change like if I call approve function then it should be changed to `Approved` and when I press decline button it should call decline function and status should be `Declined`

I tried in django shell

```
form = Leave_Management.objects.get(pk=1)
form.status = 'Approved'
```

But i dont think this is the right way of changing value problematically.And it doesnt change the default value.

How can i achieve that? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you call `form.save()` after you updated your value?

Comment: @Rakesh opps, i forgot that i need to save it to make changes... thanks a lot.. now its working as desired..

Answer (score 0):

Please refer django-fsm library [Here](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm)

you can easily use this lib. as it is simple to achieve your goal